# Setting elements in a table to be focused by tabbing

Tags: javascript, html, tabbing

I have a table that I need to make focusable by tabbing. Right now as I tab through my page it will jump over the table entirely. I have added a `href="#"` and that allows tab focus on the element I put that on, but that breaks my onclick Javascript that I have. Is there any other way to do this other then doing tab indexing?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your questions entirely but if you are talkinf about form fill ups then use this method, and tab the input fields with a tab.. You can also change tab numbers accordingly,

```
    <form>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><input tabindex="1" name=""/></td>
    <td><input tabindex="3" name=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input tabindex="2" name=""/></td>
    <td><input tabindex="4" name=""/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: This is the other solution I tried. But im using velocity framework and im using multiple .vms taped together (not my design) And we are trying to make the web applications accessible as possible starting with simple things like just being able to navigate 'fluently' with a keyboard. Only issue I run into with tab indexing is that there are some random .vms being brought in that HAVE tab indexing, done as bad practice. We are trying to avoid going through everything to make sure its all tabbed indexed correctly due to it being so tedious. But i guess we might have to resort to that.

Comment: another problem with tab indexing is, the table is dynamically populated. So the table could consist of 1 row or 100's and Im not sure how tab indexing that would work

Comment: Also to clarify Since there is no focus by tabbing,a screen reader on basic settings will come to the table, say "hey theres a table here" but skip all its contents which completely defeats the purpose of the page. So we are trying to draw attention to the table in the simplest way possible just to show the user that "Hey, this pages main function and information is here".

Comment: What I have understood from your comments and question is that you want to allow users to goto the next level in one page with tab key.. is it? if yes, then you should try for jquery they have nice key events as well.

Comment: Ok i will look into that and update you later. Thanks for spending your time to comment and help out!